# SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict ProcessedUserList DisplayName values

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, javascript, 2016, people-picker

I've used this code (found on this site) to access a people picker field in SP2016:

```
var peoplePickerID = "field title"; 
var clientPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[$('[title^="' + peoplePickerID + '"]')[0].id];
```

Seems to work well and I've console logged the output that looks like this image below. (Have redacted info but the basics are there.)

What I need to do is get the DisplayName from the ProcessedUserList. There may be more than one name in the field.

Any ideas how to get the DisplayName?

[image: screen cap of console]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the display name of users from people picker field using below code:

```
var peoplePickerID = "TestPersonField";
var clientPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[$('[title^="' + peoplePickerID + '"]')[0].id];
var peoplePickerUsersInfo = clientPeoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
if (peoplePickerUsersInfo.length > 0) {
    for(var index = 0; index < peoplePickerUsersInfo.length; index++) {
        console.log(peoplePickerUsersInfo[index].DisplayText);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Update from comments**:

If above code is not working for you, you can use below code to extract "DisplayName" from "ProcessedUserList":

```
var peoplePickerID = "TestPersonField";
var clientPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[$('[title^="' + peoplePickerID + '"]')[0].id];
var processedUserList = clientPeoplePicker.ProcessedUserList;
var objectKeys = Object.keys(clientPeoplePicker.ProcessedUserList);

for(var i = 0; i < objectKeys.length; i++) {
    if(processedUserList[objectKeys[i]].hasOwnProperty("DisplayName")) {
        var displayName = processedUserList[objectKeys[i]].DisplayName;
        console.log(displayName);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's coming up with a length = 0. Need to look inside the **ProcessedUserList** to get the **DisplayName**.  How to do that?

Comment: Are you getting empty array while using `GetAllUserInfo()`? It is working fine for me (check screenshot in my answer). Where are you adding this code, new/edit form or display form of list?

Comment: Check updated answer for fetching "DisplayName" from "ProcessedUserList".

Comment: Here's the code:

` function getAssignedTo()
 {
  alert("we're in the getAssignedTo function");
  var peoplePickerID = "Assigned To"; 
  var clientPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[$('[title^="' + peoplePickerID + '"]')[0].id];
  console.log(clientPeoplePicker);
  var getList = clientPeoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
  console.log(getList);
  if (getList > 0) {
   for(var index = 0; index < getList.length; index++){
    console.log(getList[index].DisplayText);
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: It should be `if (getList.length > 0)`. You can use my code as it is. You just need to change the `peoplePickerID` to "Assigned To". Try both solutions given above.

Comment: I'm getting an empty object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137937/discussion-between-whahoo-and-ganesh-sanap).

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Can you add the complete code you are using to your original question by editing it? I will have a look at it.